# Open Chrome in a new window (Chrome app)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to create a chrome app that when i click on a button, it opens a new chrome window, at the moment it just opens a new tab.

html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<button>Test</button>

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    window.open(
      "https://www.google.com",
      "_blank",
      "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400"
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: Stop voting down just because you dont know how to solve it.

Comment: Try reading this first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, there's no way to do that that I know of.

Using `window.open` in an app's context is a bit of a hack, but results in the URL being open in the user's default browser (not necessarily Chrome). There's no control as to how the browser chooses to open it.

There's a Chrome App specific API that was created specifically with "open a page in Chrome" in mind, [`chrome.browser`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/browser). However, it still doesn't provide an option to open in a new window.

---

The closest you can get is to create your own "browser": an app window with a `<webview>` in it. Then you have full control over presentation, but it's not integrated with Chrome's profile and may require additional work to implement things like dialogs and browser controls. See the [Browser sample app](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/webview-samples/browser) and [`<webview>` documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview).

Answer (score 0):

You missed out " on the end of the line

```
window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
```

Comment: @RhysEdwards Just copy this line of code and run it in console on Google Chrome. On my PC is work fine. Make sure working to you too.

Comment: In your browser, it works fine. The question is about Chrome App platform, not a browser.

Comment: Note: I edited the question to remove the typo. This is not the issue here.

Answer (score -1):

this creates new window in chrome app

```
chrome.app.window.create('https://www.google.com', {
    id: "MyApp",
    outerBounds: {width: 400, height: 400}
});
```

If you want an external URL then u should use

```
<webview src="http://news.google.com/" width="640" height="480"></webview>
```

for more details on dynamically changing the src property, follow [the Link](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external#webview)

Comment: It doesn't apply to Chrome Apps.