# How to open a browser app which is listed in chrome://apps

Tags: javascript, browser, web-applications, progressive-web-apps, chromium

**Chromium-based browser** has the apps page at **chrome://apps**

There are some apps that I have installed into it. Is it able to launch one of them **from JavaScript** somewhat just like opening file selecting box?

I can open chrome://apps by setting this URL in to a link, but how about a single app?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40488271/open-chrome-in-a-new-window-chrome-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from: [Open Chrome in a new window (Chrome app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40488271/open-chrome-in-a-new-window-chrome-app)

Sadly, there's no way to do that I know of.

Using window.open in an app's context is a bit of a hack, but results in the URL being open in the user's default browser (not necessarily Chrome). There's no control as to how the browser chooses to open it.

There's a Chrome App-specific API that was created specifically with "open a page in Chrome" in mind, [chrome.browser](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/browser). However, it still doesn't provide an option to open in a new window.

The closest you can get is to create your own "browser": an app window with an  in it. Then you have full control over the presentation, but it's not integrated with Chrome's profile and may require additional work to implement things like dialogs and browser controls. See the [Browser sample app](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/webview-samples/browser) and  [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview).

Answer (score 1):

You may need the app id which you can then append to the URL. I am not entirely sure how you would find but if you go to the apps page on chrome, drag the icon of the app to the search bar in the browser, you should get the full link.

For instance, I dragged the Google Slides Icon onto the search bar and it gave me this url `chrome-extension://aapocclcgogkmnckokdopfmhonfmgoek/main.html`. So, you may give it a shot! Try to open the chrome apps page, then drag the app you want to open in new tab onto the search bar.

Hence, using Javascript:

`window.open("chrome-extension://aapocclcgogkmnckokdopfmhonfmgoek/main.html", "_blank");`

Opens Google Slides App in a new tab.